# Is it possible to verify randomness?

Tags: random

Suppose we have a random generator, how do we test the randomness of its output?

If I made two calls, there is a slight chance that the two results collide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [random number generator testers](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php). They run various test such as checking whether the average of the numbers is the center of the numbers. However, such tests are not conclusive, i.e. it is possible to have a faulty random number generator which passes all the tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can run statistical tests on the output.

Chapter 3 of Knuth's [Art of computer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) discusses it in depth.